# how to replace text with numerical vaue in excel

Tags: excel

I having a response in excle cell as below

> "abx:hi,systemTime:120202020202"

In which i want to replace

> systemTime:120202020202

with empty space. I tried with `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"systemTime",""), ":","")`but not working as expected. Could you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("systemTime",A1)-1)
```

**EDIT:** As per comments

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND("systemTime",A1)-1,FIND(",",MID(A1,FIND("systemTime",A1)-1,LEN(A1)-FIND("systemTime",A1)))),"")
```

Comment: its actually a json response which has multiple attributes with values before that text

Comment: @Mallik - So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: i have a json response in which i need to replacesystemTime along with its value to null

Comment: @Mallik - Is `systemTime:.....` followed by a `,`. Can you give some complete sample text.

Comment: "attrib2":"val2","systemTime":1499242514,"attr1":"val1","attr1":"val1","attr1":"val1"

Comment: my output should be "attrib2":"val2","attr1":"val1","att‌​r1":"val1","attr1":"‌​val1"